# charCodeAt: sorting letters in string if alphabetical order

Tags: javascript

52. Write a JavaScript program to convert the letters of a given string in alphabetical order.

    ```
    function transform52 (){

        var str = document.getElementById("string52").value;
        toArray = str.split();

            for(i=0 ; i<toArray.length - 1 ; i++){//Input: ba
                if (toArray[i].charCodeAt(0) > toArray[i+1].charCodeAt(0) ){        // true
                    var temp;
                    temp = toArray[i];                              // temp = b
                    toArray[i] = toArray[i+1]               // toArray[0] = a
                    toArray[i+1] = temp;                          // toArray[1] = b
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("result52").innerHTML = toArray.join(""); //Output: ba         :(
    }
    ```

    I'm very new in JavaScript and I'm trying to solve this exercise, but the result is wrong, and I don't really understand why.

Why isn't my code working?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the result is wrong"?  Also, what does "convert the letters in alphabetical order" mean?  Do you simply want to sort the characters in a string, or do you somehow want to convert them to something else?

Comment: When comparing strings or individual characters "alphabetically," you probably mean lexicographically, which you correctly do in JavaScript via `String#localeCompare`, not comparison of char codes.

Comment: a little advice: look at an ascii table, all capital letters are before the small ones.. and the order for the accented letters can be even more wrong, not a very good way

Comment: The result is wrong because when i input "ba" it returns "ba" while it should return "ab" so this should sort given letters in string in alphabetical order.

Comment: I should be expecting there is a method in js to do this, thanks for all your comments

Comment: Have you checked what the `toArray` contains in the console? Like this, `toArray` contains 1 element, being the same as `str`, as you should use `str.split("");`. And furthermore I agree that using `charCodeAt` only works if you only use lowercase letters, and that this single loop only works for 2 letter input, you'd need 2 nested loops to get all letters at the right position in the array.

Comment: @melekk94 actually T.J. Crowder gave you already the method to do this, look for `localeCompare` function

Answer (score 0):

You should call `split` with empty string to get an array of characters.

```js
function transform52() {
    const str = document.getElementById("string52").value;
    const toArray = str.split("");

    for (i = 0; i < toArray.length - 1; i++) { //Input: ba
        if (toArray[i].charCodeAt(0) > toArray[i + 1].charCodeAt(0)) { // true
            var temp;
            temp = toArray[i]; // temp = b
            toArray[i] = toArray[i + 1] // toArray[0] = a
            toArray[i + 1] = temp; // toArray[1] = b
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result52").innerHTML = toArray.join(""); //Output: ba :(
}

transform52();
```

```html
<input id="string52" type="text" value="ba" />
<div id="result52" />
```

Comment: In future, be careful not to change the code in **questions** - by doing so you can invalidate the question. See [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function transform52 (){

          var str = document.getElementById("string52").value,
          toArray = str.split("").sort();

             document.getElementById("result52").innerHTML = toArray.join("");
    }
```

Here is my solution, cant belive this was that easy :)

Comment: the little problem here is that `sort` function also compare unicode indexes, not alphbetical order. Test your function with `"bcàaB"` for example..